# An estimation of the largest eigenvalue of a submatrix of $\left(\cos(\frac{kl\pi}{4n})\right)_{k,l=1}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis

Let us consider the following matrix $A=(a_{k,l})$ where
$$A=\left(\cos(\frac{kl\pi}{4n})\right)_{k,l=1}^n$$
Let us consider the submatrix $A_0$ of $A$ whose entries are those   $a_{k,l}$ where $k\equiv_43$ and $l\equiv_4 3$.   Let $\lambda$ be the largest eigenvalue of $A_0$.

When $n$ is even, is there any approach to prove that:  the  largest eigenvalue of $A_0$ is strictly less than $\sqrt{\frac{2n+1}{4}}$?